# Why cron executes php script a little bit differently?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have `file1.php` which includes a function from other `file2.php`. There are executing `MySQL` queries which select and insert information in that function. 
First, it is executing select query, then everything is writing to array, then from array is inserting to `MySQL` database again. 
It works fine when function is executing in browser but script in function nothing inserts in `MySQL` database when `cron` executes function (there are other `MySQL` and arrays commands which work fine with `cron`).

I have no idea what it could be.

I have tried debug and output `cron` executing but unsuccessfully.

Code that doesn't work in function when `cron` is executing it but works then executing in browser.

```
<?php    
 global $db;
$mycfg_channels = mycfg('channels');
$mycfg_lang = mycfg('lang');
$_channels = db_query("SELECT id, xmlid, chname FROM `program_name` WHERE `enable`=1 AND `id` IN ({$mycfg_channels});");
$channels = array();
foreach (explode(",", $mycfg_channels) as $v) {
$channels[$v]= @$_channels[$v];
           }
     $result = $db->sql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users_export`;");
         $operats = array();
      while ($row = $db->sql_fetchassoc($result)) {
                $operats[]= $row['username'];
            }
            $operators_channels = array();
foreach ($operats as $key => $value) {
 $channels_id_response = $db->sql_query("SELECT `channels_id` FROM `users_export` WHERE `username`= '{$value}'");

                $row = array();
                $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($channels_id_response);
                foreach ($row as $val) {
                    $ch_value = $val;
                }
 $channels_id_exploded = explode(",", $ch_value);
                $allowed_channels = array();
                foreach ($channels_id_exploded as $ch) {
                    $allowed_channels[] = $ch;
                }
                $operator_channels_from_mycfg = array();
         foreach($allowed_channels as $ch) {
foreach ($channels as $c) {
    if ($ch == $c['xmlid']){
$operator_channels_from_mycfg[] = $c;
    }}
}
foreach ($operats as $key => $val) {
    if ($value == $val ) {
foreach ($operator_channels_from_mycfg as $k => $v) {
      $operators_channels[$val][]= $v['xmlid'];
    }
    }   
}
} 
$operators_channels_delta = array();
foreach ($operators_channels as $key => $value) {

  foreach ($value as $k => $v) {

    $delta_from_db = $db->sql_query("SELECT `{$key}_delta` from `program_schedule` WHERE `chid`='{$v}'");    
     while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($delta_from_db)) {

   $operators_channels_delta[$key][$v] = $row[$key+'_delta'];  
            }
  }

  }
  var_dump($operators_channels_delta);

foreach ($operators_channels_delta as $key => $value) {

foreach ($value as $k => $val) {
if (isset($val)){
$db->sql_query("UPDATE `program_schedule` SET `{$key}_delta`= '{$val}' WHERE `chid`={$k}");
}}
    }


?>
```

It's output of `syslog`. When `cron` executes script:

```
Nov 19 14:09:01 media CRON[1689]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) >> /var/log/cronlog 2>&1)
Nov 19 14:09:01 media CRON[1693]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/StartStop/html/includes/cron_1sec.php >> /var/log/cronlog 2>&1)
Nov 19 14:09:01 media CRON[1688]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Nov 19 14:09:01 media CRON[1687]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

When I manually execute script in browser:

```
Nov 19 14:12:01 media CRON[3132]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/StartStop/html/includes/cron_1sec.php >> /var/log/cronlog 2>&1)
Nov 19 14:12:01 media CRON[3131]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

It was unsuccessfull to make getting output through MTA.

What info about environment variables can I get from that output? In file `/var/log/cronlog` I get only `PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Please, provide exact code examples and your `php` configuration.

Comment: Are you using Environment variables or a `.env` file ?    
Is the user executing the `cron` the same as the one you use to execute the script manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at the PHP LOGs, is an error occurring?

When you run a PHP script using crontab, the active directory from which it is performed is not the same as when your web server does. Try requiring the file file2.php in file1.php using absolute paths (from the root of the disk).

Comment: Logs are like this `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`. It seems like arrays could be just empty. But there is other code with arrays and data from database and it is all good.

Comment: @MantasKildišis check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog

Answer (score 0):

When you call a PHP file from command line, you are using the current environment. Make sure that your crontab uses the same environment.

Comment: `Crontab` file `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` and `environment` file `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`
How could I check what environment variable is using when PHP file is executing in the browser?